# How to implement a photo gallery that is scrollable both vertical and horizontal

Tags: ios, iphone, gallery

I'm trying to implement a photo gallery like below structure:

```
Gallery A
    Image_A1    Image_A2   ...  Image_An <----> horizontal scroll 


Gallery B
    Image_B1    Image_B2   ...  Image_Bn <----> horizontal scroll 

 ,
/|\
 |
 |
 |   vertical scroll
 |
 |
\|/
 '

Gallery X
    Image_X1    Image_X2   ...  Image_Xn <----> horizontal scroll
```

Is there a 3rd party library? How could I implement this kind of gallery?

Answer (score 1):

This is not very hard to implement. You must know the basics of iOS elements, such as `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

**To achieve this functionality, you could use the mix of both. The `UITableView` would be your main element and it provides vertical scroll out of the box.**

You would have to create custom `UITableViewCell` that would have `UICollectionView` as it's subview. Then you would have to create the `UICollectionViewCell` that would contain an `UIImageView`. The collection view would have to be modified a little to achieve horizontal scrolling.

*Alternatively, you can also embbed another `UIScrollView` into the `UITableViewCell` and implement the image displaying yourself.*

Additional information for both classes available from **Apple** docs:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html

**If you are a beginner I would suggest you try to implement this on your own, because you will learn and get experience with iOS.**

There are a few libraries available that contain the functionality you are looking for:

- [FB-Gallery](https://github.com/Seitk/FB-Gallery)
- [MHVideoPhotoGallery](https://github.com/mariohahn/MHVideoPhotoGallery)